# Dimensions of the Copper/Outer/Olah Mizbeach in the Mishkan

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, size

There is a machlokes as to the dimensions of the Copper mizbeach of the Mishkan (Zevachim 59b). One of the disputes is the dimensions of the upper part of the mizbeach where the cohanim would be walking around on, the wood and fire was, the ashes were piled up etc. According to Rebbe Yehuda the dimensions were 10x10 amos, according to Rebbe Yose it was 5x5 amos (the wood [and fire] itself was 1x1). The Rambam rules like Rebbe Yose.

Two questions:
1- according to both positions, that's a pretty small area to work with. Does anyone discuss the practicality of doing the avodah in such a small area (with such a small fire)?

2- Many pictures I have seen of the mizbeach with cohanim doing the avodah seem grossly out of proportion according to this. Am I missing something? (See attached picture for an example.).
[image]

Comment: Re 1: most of the avoda wasn't done up on top.

Comment: Is that picture of the Mishkan or of the Mikdash? The Mizbeach in the Mikdash was much bigger, see Middot 3:1.

Comment: @DoubleAA The mishkan. It's from the sidra Vayikra.

Comment: Hard to say that the picture is from the Mishkan as it has the small ramps and the protusions in middle instead of just the design in middle to separate, both signs that it's from the Mikdash